# Classic ASP getting value after every comma with regex from a string

Tags: regex, asp-classic

Fairly new to classic ASP(maintaining legacy applications) and I need to figure out how to fish out values from a string. String itself can look something like this - `0,12,234,543`. I was thinking about making a function where I can specify which number I want from the string for ex.

```
Function fnGetNumber(string, 3)
  // returns the third number(number after the second comma ie. 234)
End Function
```

The string will always have only numbers and always 4 of them. Also they will not have decimal places.

The function itself is not a problem, but I can't figure out the regex.

Comment: No need for RegEx, use [Split](http://www.devguru.com/technologies/vbscript/13973).

Comment: @Passerby Due to the strings coming from the database and they're being displayed through iteration I can not use `Split(records("string"), ",")`, will return an error.

Comment: What error? `Split` _returns_ an array, not _convert_ the string into an array. As long as you provide a valid string, it will work.

Comment: I know. Error - "Cannot use parentheses when calling a Sub".

Comment: That's just a syntax error, and it's about a line calling a Sub, which doesn't seem to have something to do with your posted question. Can you post more related code?

Comment: My question seems similar and has regexp answer in it;

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17609031/handling-series-of-comma-separated-values-in-vba

Comment: the function you showed is what, always returning the third number? You can use Instr and find the 2nd comma, then again on the 3rd comma, then use mid and go from the first instr to the second instr value. You should use split though, and take the value from the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Split is the way, use it to transform the string to an array and pull the data from that.

I wouldn't recommend regex as whilst it powerful, its readability is poor.