# Limit number of digits after comma in textbox

Tags: excel, vba, textbox

I have a textbox in userform which will be filled only with digits, commas, or dots. I know how to restrict use of only those characters. My question is it possible to limit filling value to 2 digits after coma/dot?

So when I enter value like: `1023,456` it would not let me type `6` without any action.

Editted:
I can't get this... I tried testing codes given here: [Regex to match 2 digits, optional decimal, two digits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014284/regex-to-match-2-digits-optional-decimal-two-digits) However it matches too many things. When I type more then 2 digits after comma it still matches as good string. I used for example:

`\d{0,2}(\,\d{1,2})?` 
`[0-9]?[0-9]?(\,[0-9][0-9]?)?`

What I am doing wrong?

```
Private Sub netto_Change()

Dim regEx As New VBScript_RegExp_55.RegExp

regEx.Pattern = "\d{0,2}(\,\d{1,2})?"

If regEx.Test(netto.Value) = True Then MsgBox ("It works!")

End Sub
```

Edit 2:
Okay, I am really close I got this code: `^[0-9]+[\,\.]?[0-9]?[0-9]$` but one thing is missing. This pattern should also apply to string like: `321,` with comma\dot at the end but without anything after that.

What to do?

Comment: Post the code you are using to process the textbox value.

Comment: Does a comma represent a thousands separator or a decimal point or neither in your application?

Comment: @rajah9 It's a decimal point. So it's a case of not adding more digits than it's possible - especially by accident.

Comment: @Gary'sStudent So far I haven't thought of any way to achieve it. I am not really sure if it is even possible.

Comment: VBA can use regex. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17609031/handling-series-of-comma-separated-values-in-vba/17609273#17609273 . If you change the .pattern so that it has a ",dd" then it would accept only 2 digits after the comma.

Comment: @rajah9 sounds interesting, got to read more about it.

Comment: @rajah9 I tried your idea but I can't make it work...

Comment: @Gary'sStudent, maybe you have an idea?

Comment: @Lowak:  give me about 2 hours

Comment: @Gary'sStudent Ok, thanks for getting involved :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found some time to think and I came up with a different idea on how to cope with that.

First of all I used `KeyPress` event to prevent input of any characters different then 0-9, comma and dot. To make my code work as I wanted I added code to `Change` event. `If sentence` checks whether there is comma or dot in my texbox input. If it is, limits maxlength.

```
Private Sub netto_Change()

Dim znaki As Byte

znaki = Len(netto.Value)


If InStr(1, netto.Value, ".", vbTextCompare) > 0 Or InStr(1, netto.Value, ",", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then

    If netto.MaxLength = znaki + 1 Or netto.MaxLength = znaki Then

    Else
    netto.MaxLength = znaki + 2

    End If

Else
netto.MaxLength = 0

End If

End Sub

Private Sub netto_KeyPress(ByVal KeyAscii As MSForms.ReturnInteger)

Select Case KeyAscii

    Case Asc("0") To Asc("9")
    Case Asc(",")
    Case Asc(".")
    Case Else
    KeyAscii = 0

End Select

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The Textbox controls (there are at least two: ActiveX and UserForm) have events that can be used to QA the data.

On a UserForm:

```
    Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
        ' QA text here
    End Sub
```

There are other events, like KeyDown() and Exit() that may work better.

Comment: Take a stab at it and make a new thread with your code. State what kind of textbox you are using and where it is: a control on a sheet, UserForm.

Answer (score 0):

This assumes you have event code to trap **after** the user completes entry to the TextBox.  That code should call the following function.  The function will return **True** if the string is good, **False** if the string is bad.  Your code must decide how to handle **False** :

```
Public Function QualCheck(S As String) As Boolean
    Dim L As Long, CH As String, I As Long
    QualCheck = False
    L = Len(S)
    For I = 1 To L
        CH = Mid(S, I, 1)
        If CH Like "[0-9]" Or CH = "." Or CH = "," Then
        Else
            MsgBox "bad character " & CH
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next I
    If InStr(S, ".") + InStr(S, ",") = 0 Then
        QualCheck = True
        Exit Function
    End If
    If InStr(S, ".") > 0 Then
        ary = Split(S, ".")
        If Len(ary(1)) > 2 Then
            MsgBox "too many characters after ."
        Else
            QualCheck = True
        End If
        Exit Function
    End If
    If InStr(S, ",") > 0 Then
        ary = Split(S, ",")
        If Len(ary(1)) > 2 Then
            MsgBox "too many characters after ,"
        Else
            QualCheck = True
        End If
    End If
End Function
```

NOTE:

This code does not rely on **regEx**

Comment: Well, actually not `after` but `on change`. That's why 3rd digit after comma/dot cannot be typed or can be typed but must be deleted immediately.

Comment: Thanks for your effort! If you have an idea it would be great to test it.